# Camera keeps rotating instead of changing angle

Tags: silverlight, xna, silverlight-5.0

I'm starting on silverlight 3d and I think I'm using an incorrect method to adjust the camera position. I have a slider control that has a minimum value of 0 and max of 360.

I want to move change the camera angle based on the slider value. What happens instead is that the camera keeps on rotating non-stop around the object whenever there's a change on the slider value.

here's the bit of code that adjusts the camera angle:

```
_rotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), MathHelper.ToRadians(_cameraAngle));

 // set camera position
 _cameraPosition = Vector3.Transform(_cameraPosition, _rotationMatrix);

 // set view matrix and projection matrix
 _view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(_cameraPosition, objectPosition, Vector3.Up);
 _projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, 1.667f, nearClip, farClip);
```

temporarily, I'm updating the `_cameraAngle` on the same Draw event to `0.0f` to stop the rotation but there must be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I’m guessing that you are rotating the camera at each frame. In that case, the camera will keep rotating as long as _cameraAngle has a value different from zero.
What you could do instead is something like this:

```
_rotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), MathHelper.ToRadians(_cameraAngle));

// set camera position
var currentPosition = Vector3.Transform(_cameraPosition, _rotationMatrix);

// set view matrix and projection matrix
_view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(currentPosition, objectPosition, Vector3.Up);
_projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, 1.667f, nearClip, farClip);
```

The _cameraPosition now represents the cameras original position, and the currentPosition is the camera position in the current fram.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is something like this:

```
var rotation = Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.Up, MathHelper.ToRadians(_cameraRotationDegrees);
_view = Matrix.CreateTranslation(_position) * rotation;
_projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, 1.667f, nearClip, farClip);
```

This should do the trick. Always remember to multiply the translation matrix with the rotation matrix, and not the other way around.

If you do, it will rotate your camera first, and THEN move (which wouldn't matter if you're at 0,0,0 anyway, but as soon as you move, it will mess it all up)

Alternatively you can do:

```
_view = Matrix.CreateTranslation(_position) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(_cameraRotationDegrees.Y)) * (REPEAT FOR Z AND THEN X);
```